# from query with three parametres

Tags: java, sqlite

I´m trying to make a SQLite query.

Whith TWO params works right!

```
Query query = mSession.createQuery("from Orden where nombre = :conductor AND termino = :termino");
```

But when i try with THREE params it doesn´t works, i´ve tried with:

```
Query query = mSession.createQuery("from Orden where nombre = :conductor AND estado = : estado AND termino = :termino");
Query query = mSession.createQuery("from Orden where nombre = :conductor , estado = : estado AND termino = :termino");
Query query = mSession.createQuery("from Orden where nombre = :conductor ; estado = : estado AND termino = :termino");
```

Which is the right way?

Thaks for your help!

Comment: The first one is correct except for the space between `:` and `estado`.

Comment: What error, or what results do you get with the first one?

Comment: Fixed with the first one and withouth the space between  : and estado.

Comment: @vlopezla And does it now work? If not, what "doesn't work" as you expected?

Comment: fixed and worked with the first one and withouth the space between : and estado

Answer (score 0):

The first one.

SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM tableName WHERE condition1 AND/OR condition2 AND/OR condition3